# How can I debug an MSBuild file?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I've got a large solution that I'm using TFS (and MSBuild) to... well... build. However, it takes a long time to build everything, and I was wondering if it was possible to just debug the build XML file rather than doing the build itself.

I'm using VS2008 and TFS 2008.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately the possibility to debug MSBuild scripts with Visual Studio has been [unofficially introduced in .NET 4.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio/).

For earlier versions all you are left with is "*debugging by tracing*", that is inserting log statements at key points in your script, running the script and examining the output.

Here's how you would typically do it using the [Message Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/message-task):

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <SomeVariable>foo</SomeVariable>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="MyTarget">
        <!-- Some tasks -->
        <Message Text="The value of SomeVariable is: $(SomeVariable)" Importance="High" />
        <!-- Some tasks -->
    </Target>
</Project>
```

You can then invoke the script from the command line and redirect the output to a log file:

```
msbuild MyScript.proj /t:MyTarget > %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MyScript.log
```

Related resources:

- [Debugging MSBuild scripts with Visual Studio (.NET 4.0)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio/)
- [Overview of Logging in MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild)

Comment: In order to get the message to display in Visual Studio I had to set `Importance="High"`. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557562/how-do-i-get-the-message-msbuild-task-to-shows-up-in-the-visual-studio-project

Comment: Did anyone tried the "Debugging MSBuild scripts with Visual Studio (.NET 4.0)" with Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: @enrico Campidoglio I get the following error when I try this "error MSB4066: The attribute "Name" in element <Target> is unrecognized." What should be in the place of "MyTarget" is that the build configuration?