# How do I get the <Message> MSBuild task to show up in the Visual Studio project output?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'm trying to *[printf debug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging#Techniques)* my Visual Studio project file by spewing messages to the console like this:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Message Text="+++++++++++++++++++++++ Justin Dearing ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" />
</Target>
```

This works from the command line:

```
BeforeBuild:
  +++++++++++++++++++++++ Justin Dearing ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

However, the messages don't show up in the Visual Studio 2010 build output. Is there an alternative MSBuild task I can use, or a setting in Visual Studio I can enable to make these messages appear?

Comment: I recently found and used the possibility to [debug MSBuild with Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio/) - including breakpoints, variable inspection, and stuff. It's amazingly helpful with complicated build projects.  
(You need to modify the registry to enable the undocumented `/debug` switch in MSBuild which lets you attach a debugger upon build start)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Add the `Importance` attribute with value *High* to `Message`.

Like this:

```
<Message Importance="High" Text="+++ Justin Dearing +++" />
```

Answer (score 51):

To change the build output verbosity shown in the Visual Studio 2010 window, open the *Options* dialog and select the *Build and Run* settings below the *Projects and Solutions* node.

Unless you explicitly specify a low message importance, your messages should show up at *Normal* verbosity or higher.

Comment: Another idea is to set the `Condition` parameter of the `Message` task so that it is of high importance when in `Debug` mode but low when in `Release`.

Answer (score 41):

For anyone reading this with MSBuild 16, bear in mind that you can't use `message` at the project level. You now need to first define `InitialTargets`

```
<Project InitialTargets="Test" ...
```

And then create a task to place the message in:

```
  <Target Name="Test">
      <Message Importance="High" Text="A Message" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Instead of `InitialTargets` at `project` level, also you can explicitly specify before or after each existing target it should be executed. Like `<Target Name="Test" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">`

Answer (score 3):

In VisualStudio 2019 a `<Message>` disappears from Build log if any `<Error>` Task occurs in "Build" target (and others?) even if `<Error>` is *after* `<Message>`.

In contrast msbuild.exe 16.8.2.56705 displays `<Message>` in any case.

[Question only implies by example that BeforeBuild is used, I answered anyway as the question title and text perfectly matched my problem that the message was not shown]