# Nuget does not import .targets

Tags: nuget-package

I want to add my .targets file into project via nuget.
I have next .nuspec file:

```
<package >
  <metadata>
  ...
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\..\Rcs\Rcs\bin\Release\Rcs.targets" target="build\Rcs.targets" />
    <file src="..\..\Rcs\Rcs\bin\Release\Rcs.dll" target="lib\Xamarin.iOS10\Rcs.dll" />     


    <file src="..\..\Rcs\Rcs\bin\Release\*.dll" />
    <file src="..\..\Rcs\Rcs\bin\Release\*.config" />

  </files>
</package>
```

And .targets file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
        <RcsDirectory Condition="$(RcsDirectory) == '' Or $(RcsDirectory) == '*Undefined*'">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\</RcsDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <UsingTask
    TaskName="Rcs.RcsBuildTask"
    AssemblyFile="$(RcsDirectory)Rcs.dll" />

  <Target AfterTargets="Build" Name="RcsBuildTask">
    <RcsBuildTask
      ProjectPath="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
      RootNamespace="$(RootNamespace)"
    />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

New  doesn't added to project after installing this nuget.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure the `.targets` file is really not imported into your Nuget package?

Along with a `.nuspec` file you should use the [Nuget CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-pack) to pack your files. **Don't use the dotnet CLI**

Once you created your `.nupkg` file using the `nuget pack` command, you can open your package using [Nuget Package Explorer](http://C:%5CUsers%5Cwish%5C.nuget%5Cpackages%5Ceshcloud.logging%5C1.2.4) or simply [WinRar](https://www.win-rar.com) (I believe this should work too with 7-zip).

At this point if you see your `.targets` file or your `Rcs.dll` are missing it means you have an issue with your `.nuspec` file. 
Ensure your `.nuspec` file has the name `ProjectName.nuspec`

OR

Specify the `.nuspec` file in your `.csproj`

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  [...]
  <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
  <NuspecFile>ProjectName.nuspec</NuspecFile>
  [...]
</PropertyGroup>
```

If your `.targets` file is in your `.nupkg` then it means its execution is simply doing not what you expect.

When you install a Nuget package, the files are stored to the [Nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders). On Windows this is located at `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`. Your `.targets` file and your `Rcs.dll` should be there too

First of all you can include this in your `.targets` file

```xml
<Target Name="TestMessage" AfterTargets="Build" >
    <Message Text="***********************************************************" Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)" Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text="***********************************************************" Importance="high"/>
</Target>
```

When building your project, you will see the current folder is actually your cache (not your project's directory)

If I understand, what you want is to copy your `Rcs.dll` into your bin folder. To achieve that you can write a similar task in your `.targets` file

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\lib\Xamarin.iOS10\Rcs.dll">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

This is a normal behavior that the `.targets` file is not copied to your project referencing your Nuget package. The `.targets` file should stay in the Nuget cache, but from there, execute a MsBuild command to copy the `Rcs.dll` file.

I hope you understand my answer and it solves your problem.

Comment: What if .targets is in the nuget package, it gets "unpacked" into NuGet cache, I put the "debug" current dir printer in .targets and see that it doesn't gets called as no debug outpout is in "Build" output in the VS while I build the project with the referenced nuget package. Where would be my next "investigation point"? Thanks.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov I believe if you set `Importance="high"` your message should show up with any verbosity configuration. But just in case in your Visual Studio settings try to change the verbosity to `normal` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557945/1203116). Also with a text editor, make sure your `.targets` file in your Nuget cache has the proper format. I wrote an example in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40652794/1203116). Place your `ItemGroup` node at the correct location in between a `Project` node.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by using NuGet Package Explorer that the targets file had to be named correctly. By default, NPE uses .targtets. It appears that other names may not work.

My Id is "Handy.TargetFrameworkVersionCumulativePreprocessorSymbols", but I had named my target file "HandyTargetFrameworkVersionCumulativePreprocessorSymbols.targets".

Once I used "Handy.TargetFrameworkVersionCumulativePreprocessorSymbols" everywhere it just worked as expected.